# CSS: How to accomplish a div which is blurred at the edges?

Tags: html, css, animation

I have an idea for an Ajax-loader.

This is what I have accomplished so far:

```css
body {
  background-color: lightGrey;
  counter-reset: h1-counter;
}
.wrap {
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap div {
  background: linear-gradient(#0032f0, white, #0032f0);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: .8;
}
.wrap div.dark-bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: moveDarkBar 3s linear infinite;
  z-index: 1;
}
@keyframes moveDarkBar {
  from {
    left: -20%;
  }
  to {
    left: 120%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div></div>
  <div class="dark-bar"></div>
</div>
```

I want the moving indicator (.dark-bar) to be "melted" with foreground-div. Currently there is a hard line which is visually distinguishable.

**Is there a way to get the moving indicator (.dark-bar) to be blurred on the left-, right edge?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `CSS filter` to add `blur to top layer` which is animated as below,

> filter - The filter property provides graphical effects like blurring,
>   sharpening, or color shifting an element. Filters are commonly used to
>   adjust the rendering of images, backgrounds, and borders.

Do include `vendor prefixes` for other browsers such as `-webkit-,-o-,-moz-,-ms-` to filter.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightGrey;
  counter-reset: h1-counter;
}
.wrap {
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap div {
  background: linear-gradient(#0032f0, white, #0032f0);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: .8;
}
.wrap div.dark-bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: moveDarkBar 3s linear infinite;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-filter:blur(2px); /*Add this*/
}
@keyframes moveDarkBar {
  from {
    left: -20%;
  }
  to {
    left: 120%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div></div>
  <div class="dark-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @mizech Hope this help.

Comment: Helped indeed. ;)) Absolutely awesome !! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Welcome @mizech :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `box-shadow` property and set the vertical and horizontal axis values to 0. Something like this:

```
div {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
```

This might be a similar effect for the one you want.